# How to create a request object to get a token

Tags: python, flask, oauth-2.0, flask-oauthlib, authlib

I need to create and return a token like this :

```
@app.route('/account/login', methods=['POST'])
def login():
    if user:
        ...

        return authorization.create_token_response(request={
                'client_id': '',
                'client_secret': '',
                'grant_type': 'password',
                'username': '',
                'password': ''
            })
    else:
        ...
```

But I don't know how to build the `request` object which `create token response` receives. Can you help me, please ?

Obs : I need to filter the input data, I don't want to use `/oauth/token` as you can see [here](https://github.com/authlib/example-oauth2-server/blob/master/website/routes.py#L83)

Answer (score 1):

This use case is very weird. If you just want to generate a request object. You can create it using the class `OAuth2Request`, which you can find at:

```
from authlib.specs.rfc6749 import OAuth2Request
```